# TensorFlow: `mnist_replica.py` with two GPUs runs longer than the single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, distributed-computing

Why when I run TensorFlow `mnist_replica.py` on two machines in parallel does it take longer than training on a single machine/GPU.  Both use the same network structure and the parameters are the same. Parallelism training takes more than ten minutes when `train_steps=1000`, while a single GPU takes only 4 seconds.
thank you!

Comment: it would be helpful if you provided examples of the code and how it is setup between the two networks

Comment: Generally using multiple GPU takes more time than a single GPU. Some performance gain can be achieved by setting parallel growth.

Comment: @Bill Armstrong  thank you very very much, the code  [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/python/mnist_replica.py), I only used  its network structure and parameters in my single GPU model. the validation dataset' result almost the same.

Comment: @Jaganadh Gopinadhan    thank you,  I don't quiet understand what you said 'by setting parallel growth'.

Comment: @HgLeL : The code fragment `config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)` Refer https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu

Comment: @Jaganadh Gopinadhan：thank you, I'll have a try.